# Lighttpd + Node.JS (via ModProxy) - 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: lighttpd, node.js

At the top of my lighttpd,conf file I have the following

```
server.modules = (
"mod_access",
"mod_alias",
"mod_compress",
"mod_redirect",
# "mod_rewrite",
"mod_proxy"
)
```

At the bottom I addded

```
proxy.server = (".js" => (
    ( "host" => "127.0.0.1", "port" => 3000 )
))
```

If I go to my JS file (containing `console.log('test');`) I get an Internal Server Error

I tried putting it in a $HTTP["host"] condition, and removing .js but neither work

Node is fine, if I run `node test.js` from command line, it works

Comment: So what's the error in the Lighttpd error log?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what service is running on port 3000? Try your request directly against that port (like `curl http://localhost:3000/somename.js`).

But I think you somehow got the misconception that nodejs is like php where you can run any .js file with nodejs as you run .php with php - that is not the case. nodejs is not a "CGI" interpreter by itself (although you could probably write one with nodejs that runs other js files).